# Cant install any modules with npm. Error:spawn C:\Users\.......Microsoft VS Code ENOENT

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, node-modules

[Screen dump of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTulD.png) npm install (some module) dosent work. It leaves me with some errors starting with error: spawn : c:\my-vsc-directory

I have checked my environment PATH's [PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TrhQ.png)
I have tried this: npm config set python "c:\Python27\python.exe"

I have this installation of both vsc and nodejs on two other computers running without issues....so i think i messed upp something here. Cant find it though.

Answer (score 0):

With npm config edit i found msbuild_path: C:\path to vsc. I removed it and it worked. Maybe someone can tell me how it got there?